# Array de query nativa a objeto Java

Tags: java, hibernate, sql

Tengo un problema al realizar una query nativa, donde el resultado en SQLManager es éste:

```
Query: "select p.cod_producto, p.deno_producto, array(SELECT t.cod_tanque FROM estagas.tanqu063 t where t.cod_producto = p.cod_producto) as tanks, array(SELECT m.cod_manguera as varchar FROM estagas.tanqu063 t inner join estagas.mangu063 m on m.cod_tanque = t.cod_tanque where t.cod_producto = p.cod_producto) as hoses from estagas.produ063 p"
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En mi código realizo la consulta:

```
List<ProductsTanksHosesDTO> dto = null;
String query = "select p.cod_producto, p.deno_producto, "
            + "array(SELECT t.cod_tanque FROM estagas.tanqu063 t where t.cod_producto = p.cod_producto) as tanks, "
            + "array(SELECT m.cod_manguera as varchar FROM estagas.tanqu063 t inner join estagas.mangu063 m on m.cod_tanque = t.cod_tanque where t.cod_producto = p.cod_producto) as hoses "
            + "from estagas.produ063 p";

dto = em.createNativeQuery(query).getResultList();
```

Lo cual me genera el siguente error:

```
27-11-2017 12:33:26.090 [JavaFX Application Thread] ERROR java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ScalarResultColumnProcessor.extract(ScalarResultColumnProcessor.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ResultRowProcessor.buildResultRow(ResultRowProcessor.java:83) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.ResultRowProcessor.buildResultRow(ResultRowProcessor.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.getResultColumnOrRow(CustomLoader.java:413) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:769) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:985) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:943) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:349) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2615) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2598) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2430) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2425) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:335) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2160) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:992) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:148) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.10.Final.jar:5.2.10.Final]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:372) ~[spring-orm-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar:4.3.7.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy217.getResultList(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.avalon.localbos.service.impl.ProductServiceImpl.findAllProductsTanksHosesDTO(ProductServiceImpl.java:82) ~[classes/:na]
```

Siendo el método que provoca el error:

```
@Override
public Object extract(Object[] data, ResultSet resultSet, SharedSessionContractImplementor session)
        throws SQLException, HibernateException {
    return type.nullSafeGet( resultSet, alias, session, null );
}
```

El problema es los arrays, ya que al realizar la misma consulta sin ellos, funciona correctamente.

Mi clase productsTanksHosesDTO:

```
public class ProductsTanksHosesDTO {

private String productCode;
private String productName;
private Object[] tanks;
private Object[] hoses;

public ProductsTanksHosesDTO(String productCode, String productName, Object[] tanks, Object[] hoses) {
    this.productCode = productCode;
    this.productName = productName;
    this.tanks = tanks;
    this.hoses = hoses;
}
...
```

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente he conseguido solventarlo realizando la query nativa sin Spring, supongo que no permite la consulta de arrays por algún motivo.

La consulta quedó así:

```
Statement st = ApplicationConfiguration.dataSource().getConnection().createStatement();
ResultSet resultSet = st.executeQuery(query);
```

Donde `dataSource()` realiza la conexión a la base de datos sin el uso de Spring.

Answer (score 0):

para lograr solventar tu error, tienes que hacer doble parse en la consulta porque la verdad, pretender que la consulta nativa te la pase a una lista de objetos no es posible, por tanto lo que tienes que hacer es lo siguiente:

```
List<Object> listaObjetosNativos = em.createNativeQuery(query).getResultList();
```

Eso lo puedes recorrer asi:

```
Object[] fila;

for(Object item : listaObjetosNativos){
  fila = (Object[]) item;
  //Desde esta linea empiezas a utlizar el contenido de cada fila para pasarlo a tu POJO
}
```

Espero que te sirva la respuesta sino porfavor hazmelo saber, buen dia.

Comment: Lo probé en su momento, no llega a asignar la lista de Objects. Era problema de Spring.

Answer (score -3):

Te da error porque declaras la lista como null.
Prueba a hacer:

```
List<ProductsTanksHosesDTO> dto = new List<ProductsTanksHosesDTO>();
```

Comment: Lo he cambiado, me sigue tirando la misma traza

Comment: y haciendo un new a la hora de crear los arrays? es decir, private Object[] tanks = new Object... Lo que no se que capacidad pondría, yo para esto suelo utilizar listas

Comment: Realmente no llega a la clase ProductsTanksHosesDTO, es al obtener el result list

Comment: si es en esta línea dto = em.createNativeQuery(query).getResultList(); comprueba que em no es nulo.

Comment: Era problema de Spring, el entityManager no era nulo, ya que estaba inyectado. Gracias igualmente.